# Why does accessing the first element of a list yield "List"

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of expressions

```
listOfStuff = {-(b^(3/2)/Sqrt[7 \[Pi]]), b^(3/2)/Sqrt[7 \[Pi]]}
```

When I try to access the first element of this list like so

```
First[listOfStuff]
```

This yields

```
-(b^(3/2)/Sqrt[7 \[Pi]])
```

If I try to access it either of the following two ways

```
listOfStuff[[0]]
Part[listOfStuff, 0]
```

I get

```
List
```

The notebook literally just prints "List". I'm new to Mathematica but not new to programming languages in general. I really don't understand what is going on here. Any help understanding this would be appreciated.

Comment: `listOfStuff[[1]]` is the `First` element.

Comment: see [Head >> Properties and Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Head.html)

Comment: Oh I'm dumb. Forgot arrays start at one. Thanks.

Comment: List indexing in Mathematica starts from 1. However, the index zero contains the Head which is List in this case.